# bulkDelete method not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a command that cleans chat, so you can remove spam, or unwanted chats etc. The command has worked fine one time and hasn't worked again, so I'm inclined to think it's something out of my control, but I don't know.

```
try {
  let mod = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Mods");

  if (!message.member.roles.has(mod.id)) return message.reply('You are not allowed to use this command.');

  if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please supply a number of messages to delete.");

  if (args[0] > 100 || args[0] < 2) return message.reply('Please supply a number between 2 and 100 to delete.');

  message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0] + 1);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

As said before, it's worked as intended one time, every other time, it just deletes hundreds of messages, for seemingly no reason. Maybe it is because I'm self-hosting for now and it's a latency issue? Not sure, either way, any help would be more than greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately You've not read [official manual about bulkDelete method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete)

Otherwise You would know that it returns promise.

also keep in mind this:

> Bulk delete given messages that are newer than two weeks.
>
> This is only **available** when **using a bot account**.

So if Your account is bot account You can do it:

```
message.channel
  .bulkDelete(args[0] + 1)
  .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: So, why exactly does it matter how I catch the error, when it is a promise, good answer, just curious.

Comment: it does matter that You've to run that promise. Promise is special kind of class that has to be executed with `then` or using `async/await` sugar

Comment: Cool, just was curious as to how that worked, will keep it in mind. Thank you, appreciate the answer.